# How to download multiple audio files from url and play offline in App

Tags: ios, swift

I want to download multiple audio files from url and play offline in App . This is what i do in my coding  but some time array loop stop downloading . And Also I have one more array to download. and this code is only for download. playing audio is working proper.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Begin of code")
    self.linksToUrls()
    self.startDownloadingUrls()
    print("End of code")
 }
 // create a function to start the audio data download

func getAudioDataFromUrl(audioUrl:NSURL, completion: @escaping ((_ data: NSData?) -> Void)) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: audioUrl as URL) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data as NSData?)
        print("dfdgfdg",data!)

        }.resume()
}

// create another function to save the audio data
func saveAudioData(audio:NSData, destination:NSURL) -> Bool {
    if audio.write(to: destination as URL, atomically: true) {
        print("The file \"\(destination.lastPathComponent!)\" was successfully saved.")


        return true
    }
    return false
}

// just convert your links to Urls
func linksToUrls(){
    print("IntroductoryMusicFile1 = count = ",IntroductoryMusicFile1.count)
    audioUrls = NewsAudio1
        .map() { NSURL(string: $0) }
        .filter() { $0 != nil }
    print("introcount",IntroductoryMusicFile1.count)
    musicUrls = IntroductoryMusicFile1


        .map() { NSURL(string: $0) }
        .filter() { $0 != nil }
}



// create a loop to start downloading your urls


func startDownloadingUrls(){
    arrayplay.removeAll()
    //if  (musicUrls = "The URL?"){  }
    //   let syn = SyncBlock()
    for  url in 0 ... musicUrls.count-1 {

        let aaa = musicUrls[url]
        let audioType = audioUrls[url]
        print(aaa!)
        print("audioType",audioType!)


        if aaa == NSURL(string: ""){
            arrayplay.append("")
        }else{
            print("Started downloading \"\(String(describing: aaa?.lastPathComponent!))\".")

            let url1 =  aaa
            let request = URLRequest(url: url1! as URL)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in

                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 404{
                        print("Refresh token...")
                        // self.audioPlay()
                        self.arrayplay.append("")
                    }else{


                        self.getAudioDataFromUrl(audioUrl: aaa!) { data in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async() {



                                print("Finished downloading \"\(String(describing: aaa?.lastPathComponent!))\".")
                                print("Started saving \"\(String(describing: aaa?.lastPathComponent!))\".")
                                if self.saveAudioData(audio: data!, destination: self.documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(aaa!.lastPathComponent!)! as NSURL ) {
                                    // do what ever if writeToURL was successful
                                    //   print("",data)

                                    self.arrayplay.append(aaa!.lastPathComponent!)

                                    self.data1 = self.arrayplay as! [String]
                                    print("data1",self.data1)
                                    print("",self.data1.count)
                                    if self.data1.count == self.musicUrls.count {
                                        print("complete")
                                        self.downloadDataAnnotation()
                                    }
                                    //self.synk.complete()
                                    // print("abc")

                                } else {
                                    //  print("The File \"\(url.lastPathComponent!.stringByDeletingPathExtension)\" was not saved.")
                                }
                            }
                        }



                    }
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }


    }

}
```

Can any one suggest me the better code or any other way to download multiple audio file ...